# Regular expression to strip all HTML tags except sub & sup tags

Tags: c#, html, regex, tags

I need to strip all html tags from a string except `<sub></sub> & <sup></sup>` tags.

Suppose if a string is `"<p>Hello world</p> <span class="required">H<sub>2</sub>O</span>"`
Output should be `Hello world H<sub>2</sub>O`

Comment: See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @John - I'd never seen that before - excellent link ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using regular expressions, you may find it easier to use something like [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which gives you a read/write [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) to play with.

Comment: Someone please write a bot that answers all questions that contain "regex" _and_ "HTML" with "Html Agility Pack" ;-)

Comment: ...and linking that great article (see first question comment) about the non-regularity of html and this thus the (general) impossibility to use regex to parse it (generally, but there are tons of problems that *can* be solved, though.)

Comment: @UweKelm Popup: "Your question appears to be about parsing HTML with regexps. Perhaps you should read this first: " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454